# spring data neo4j 4.2.0.RELEASE custom query issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Here is the code :

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {

    Person findOne(Long id);
    Person findByFirstName(String firstName);
    Person save(Person person);
    boolean exists(Long id);

    List<Person> findAll();

    @Query("MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p")
    Person get(String n);}

    @NodeEntity(label = "Person")
}
```

Here is the model class :

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person{
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Person(Long id, String firstName, String lastName){
        this(firstName, lastName);
        this.id = id;
    }

    @GraphId
    @Property(name = "id")
    @Index(unique = true)
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Property(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Getter
    @Property(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Spring configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("my_package.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("my_package")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

     @Bean
     public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
         // with domain entity base package(s)
         return new SessionFactory("my_package.model");
     }

     @Bean
     public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
         return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
     }

 }
```

Maven pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.14</lombok.version>
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.14</lombok.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <neo4j.version>3.1.2</neo4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Default CRUD methods provided by spring data work fine, but the one with custom Cypher query does not work. I am not really familiar with Cypher, but taking into account other examples I have seen so far it should work. Am I missing some dependencies or something?
Here is the code raising problems:

```
@Test
public void testFindFriendsById(){
    Person main = new Person(10L, "mainname", "mainlastnmame");

    personRepository.save(main);

    // here is that custom method from PersonRepository
    // having this query : @Query("MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p")
    Person person = personRepository.get(main.getFirstName());

    assertThat(person, is(notNullValue()));
}
```

Any suggestions?

UPD: I am using TestServer for testing :

```
protected static TestServer testServer;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupTestServer() {
    testServer = new TestServer.Builder().port(2222).build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turned out that Spring doesnt bound parameters to queries automatically.

```
@Query("MATCH (p:Person) where p.firstName = {name} return p")
Person get(@Param("name") String name);
```

This works fine

Answer (score 0):

What should method get do? Get user by firstName? You need add filter position: filter by attribute `firstName` in `Person`.

```
@Query("MATCH (p:Person {firstName={0}}) RETURN p")
```

Comment: Lets say so, it doesnt really matter. I just want execute the simplest possible query to fetch the only Person node from the db to check that my configuration indeed works. Btw, you suggestion doesnt work - `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Invalid input '=': expected an identifier character, whitespace, ':'` even if you put `:` - still nothing.  Tried `@Query("MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.firstName = {0} RETURN p")` also nothing